# extrusion of the face of a 3D model

Tags: extrude

I am trying to extrude the surface of a lower jaw.  The surface from the outside, the inside and the top.  they are selected as one object from the stl file of a mandible.  when extruded in the z axis, one side is extruded (eg the outer) while the opposing side is extruded to the inside of the mandible.  Is there a way to extrude relative to the original object so I end up with extrusion from both sides similar to each other.[image: this picture represents the area I selected from the surface of the mandible]
[image: in this picture I want to extrude to the outer side and to the inner side as well]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> then select **Extrude along normals**.

Comment: thanks a million you rock